# Create SQL Global Temp Table while Dynamically Pivoting Years between a Date Range as Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

How would I alter the below manual DDL script in a way to instead create the table dynamically? For example I want to create 2 columns (enroll year and disenroll year) for every year between 2017 and the current year (2021) and pivot them. Currently the script will manually create the columns from 2017 until year 2021. What direction should I take to make this dynamic?

I am thinking to use while loop to accomplish this but I'm not quite sure if I'm on the right track or if there was a better way. Next year in 2022 when the script is run it should append [2022] columns. Next next year in 2023 the script should append [2023] columns and so on.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##Enrollment

CREATE TABLE ##Enrollment
(
    [ID]                      VARCHAR(10), 
    [First_Name]              VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
    [Middle_Name]             VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [Last_Name]               VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [Date_of_Birth]           DATE NULL,
    [2017_Enrollment_Date]    DATE NULL,
    [2017_Disenrollment_Date] DATE NULL,
    [2018_Enrollment_Date]    DATE NULL,
    [2018_Disenrollment_Date] DATE NULL,
    [2019_Enrollment_Date]    DATE NULL,
    [2019_Disenrollment_Date] DATE NULL,
    [2020_Enrollment_Date]    DATE NULL,
    [2020_Disenrollment_Date] DATE NULL,
    [2021_Enrollment_Date]    DATE NULL,
    [2021_Disenrollment_Date] DATE NULL,
    [Begin_Date]              DATE NULL,
    [End_Date]                DATE NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is iterating over years between a max and min, and then iterating over the 2 possible names for your dynamic columns

```
declare @minyear int = 2017
declare @maxyear int
declare @ddl varchar(max)
declare @i int = 0

if (@maxyear is null) select @maxyear=year(getdate())

drop table if exists ##Enrollment

set @ddl = 
'CREATE TABLE ##Enrollment(
 [ID]                           VARCHAR(10)
,[First_Name]                   VARCHAR (255) NULL 
,[Middle_Name]                  VARCHAR (255) NULL
,[Last_Name]                    VARCHAR (255) NULL
,[Date_of_Birth]                DATE NULL
,[Begin_Date]                   DATE NULL
,[End_Date]                     DATE NULL'

while @maxyear >= @minyear
begin    
  while @i <= 1
  begin 
    set @ddl = @ddl + char(13) + 
      ',[' + cast(@minyear as varchar(4)) + '_' + case when @i = 0 then 'En' else 'Disen' end + 'rollment_Date] DATE NULL'
    set @i = @i + 1
  end
    
  set @minyear = @minyear + 1
  set @i = 0
end 

set @ddl = @ddl + char(13) + ')'

exec (@ddl)
```

If you set a value to `@maxyear` (for example in the declaration, with `declare @maxyear int = 2023`) you can check the columns reach the year 2023.

You can test on this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b45a5114fa4c66faf44412d173833e52)